# How to access the extended function if the object is added to the parent class arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, extends

I have 2 classes - `Customer` and `PayingCustomer`, in which the latter is an extension of the former.

I am trying to access the extended methods in which the PayingCustomer object is added to the arrayList of the parent class - Customer. However, the only methods that are available for use are the methods from the parent-class in which that is not what I am looking for.

Is there a way for me to derive the extended class methods without making a massive code change as written below?

Main Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      ArrayList<Customer> cArr = new ArrayList();
      PayingCustomer c1 = new PayingCustomer ("John Doe");

      // directly accessing the extended class method with the relevant object class
      c1.setPaymentMethod("Credit"); // returns me "Credit"

      cArr.add(c1);

      System.out.println(c1.getPaymentMethod());

      //--------------------
      for (int i=0; i<cArr.size(); i++)
      {
          // Errors out, only can make use of the parent-class methods
          System.out.println(cArr.get(i).getPaymentMethod());
      }
    }
}
```

Customer Code:

```
public class Customer
{
    private String name;

    public Customer(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

PayingCustomer code

```
public class PayingCustomer extends Customer
{
    private String paymentMethod = "";
    
    public PayingCustomer(String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }

    public void setPaymentMethod(String methodInput)
    {
        paymentMethod = methodInput;
    }

    public String getPaymentMethod()
    {
        return paymentMethod;
    }
}
```

Comment: try casting it to child class

Comment: System.out.println(((PayingCustomer) cArr.get(i)).getPaymentMethod());    
This line adds cast to child class and it does the job well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list accepts the instances of Customer. While iterating it derives each member as the instance of Customer only. Cast the one to PayingCustomer if its instance of PayingCustomer and then use it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cArr.size(); i++) {
        if (cArr.get(i) instanceof PayingCustomer) {
            System.out.println(((PayingCustomer) cArr.get(i)).getPaymentMethod());
        } else {
            System.out.println(cArr.get(i).getName());
        }
    }
```